# What is the terminology for raw writes to block devices?

Tags: linux, security, block-device

I've been looking for solutions for Linux that can disable/deny attempts to write directly to block devices—preferably only certain ones like the boot disk (as with Apple's SIP)—while still permitting writes at the filesystem-level.

grsecurity is the first project I found that had this solution and is where I'm getting the idea from. The trouble with theirs is that I don't need (nor care for) the rest of what it provides and that it is too sweeping. Any block device that is mounted read-only or is unmounted will itself be made read-only (i.e., you can't run `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda1`) and they can't be (re)mounted read-write if they are like that at the time of activating the protection. Looking at their code, I managed to write a kernel module (and a kernel patch with a one-way sysctl entry) that did the same thing. I later modified the kernel module to only block raw write operations to `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sda1` based on name. Then, I rewrote it again to only block writes based on major number since I didn't know how to handle non-canonical paths.

I abandoned the kernel because a module is so much easier, but it would be even easier if I knew how to write code that could determine the boot device and its parent so I don't have to hard code the numbers. So, I've resorted to searching for a solution with Google as I figured it would be a common idea (without the targeting of the boot disk). My results have only been about raw devices, write blockers for forensics, and raw IO as it relates to memory. What would be the terminology that is used to describe a system that prohibits writing directly to data storage devices?

Comment: I'm not sure what terminology you should use to search, but it sounds like something you could implement as policy. Maybe cgroups (blkid) can help you. However, direct access to block devices usually requires root privileges. If you explain more about what you are trying to accomplish and why that restriction is insufficient, someone might be able to better point you in the right direction.

Comment: @PaulNordin Look at the top where I reference SIP.

Comment: OpenBSD had this feature (as part of [securelevel 2](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-2.7/securelevel.7)) a decade or so earlier.

Comment: I can't think of any other name than “raw write to a block device”.

Comment: @Gilles I am aware of securelevel and I tried implementing it, but it was too sweeping. I need it to work like SIP.

Comment: @Melab Yes, I saw that, but I don't think SIP does quite what you are asking. I think it's essentially implementing MAC and only permits filesystem writes to certain areas for a few whitelisted programs. I think you could achieve something very similar, but not without great pain if read only mounts are not an option (maybe SELinux or similar?). Also note that `blockdev --setro /dev/sdX` can prevent raw writes, but a regular read only file system mount doesn't.

Comment: @paulnordin It doesn't have to be like SIP, it only has to prevent writing to the root device and its parent. `blockdev --setro /dev/sdX` can be reversed by root and I'm pretty sure it also disallows filesystem writes.

Comment: @Melab That is what I thought, but I just tested it on a spare flash drive. In case it matters, the fs (ext4) was mounted first. I executed `blockdev --setro /dev/sdX`, then `touch /path/to/sdXmount/test.txt`. The file was created, but `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX` with root privileges failed. Disabling root and using sudo with limited actions could *help* the reversal by root problem, but I'm guessing programs that run as root still have free reign. Even the security programs mentioned ... can't root disable them or modify configurations/reload or unload security modules from the kernel?